# nHibernate mapping with composite key and collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am having trouble trying to map this object that contains a collection of guids.   I have the mapping working with no errors, however I keep getting empty guids inserted into OrganizationId in the OrganizationAdvertistments table.  I was wondering how to map this set correctly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<class name="Advertisement" table="Advertisement" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="guid"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="DateStart"/>
    <property name="DateExpired"/>
    <property name="Title"/>
    <property name="Body"/>

    <set name="OrganzationIds" table="OrganizationAdvertisements" lazy="true">

        <key>
            <column name="AdvertisementId"></column>
        </key>
        <element  column="OrganizationId" type="Guid" />


    </set>


</class>
```

Comment: maybe it is not GUID but UUID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you gonna have many to many relationship between Advertistment and Organization? if yes you've got had another class: Organization and set many to many relationship between these two classes and there is no need to map OrganzationIds. Your class would be somthing like this:

```
class Advertisement
{
 //other properties
 public virtual ISet<Organization> Organizations {ge;set}
}
```

and your map:

```
 <class name="Advertisement" table="Advertisement" lazy="false">  
        <id name="Id">  
            <generator class="guid"></generator>  
        </id>  
        <property name="DateStart"/>  
        <property name="DateExpired"/>  
        <property name="Title"/>  
        <property name="Body"/>  

         <set name="Organizations"
               table="OrganizationAdvertisements"
               lazy="true">
            <key column="AdvertisementId" />
            <many-to-many class="Namespace.Organization"
                          column="OrganizationID" />
          </set>
    </class>
```